# load img src dynamically from local assets based on API response Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js

I have searched for some time before to ask this question I hope it's not duplicated question

I use Vue.js, with Laravel as API

I have a page that request data from API

API response

I need to show this image on `<b-img>` tag

```
basicPlan: {
     title: 'title',
     img: '../../../assets/images/illustration/Pot3.svg',
      Price: 750,
},
```

In my template where I have this code component located in `'src/views/user/plan.vue'`

```
 <b-img
    :src="plan.img"
    class="mb-2 mt-5"
    alt="basic svg img"
 />
```

I got this error

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../../../assets/images/illustration/Pot1.svg'"

but if I hard code the src work normally
this works fine without v-bind

```
 <b-img
    src="../../../assets/images/illustration/Pot3.svg"
    class="mb-2 mt-5"
    alt="basic svg img"
 />
```

vue.config.js config

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        options.transformAssetUrls = {
          img: 'src',
          image: 'xlink:href',
          'b-avatar': 'src',
          'b-img': 'src',
          'b-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
          'b-card': 'img-src',
          'b-card-img': 'src',
          'b-card-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
          'b-carousel-slide': 'img-src',
          'b-embed': 'src',
        }
        return options
      })
  },
```

Any solution

I may have more than one plan

Comment: When webpack transforms the assets, it resolves from the `src` folder. Try removing `../../../` from `basicPlan.img` used in the `:src` binding because it is no longer necessary (assuming you have `src/assets`?)